# One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, keychain

I am trying to import the Certificates to iOS Simulator from Keychain app. When I drag and drop the certificate in the Simulator. It shows this popup.

[image]

#### Important observation

When I drag and drop a **Root certificate** it is imported successfully but when I try the same thing with **Standard certificate**, it fails to do that.

[image]

Blue certificates are : standard certificates
Golden certificates are: root certificate

Answer (score 5):

This is likely caused by the `errSecParam` from the `Security` framework. Either your certificate contains items the Keychain doesn't support, or the format is something the Keychain cannot decode.

You could try to transform your certificate from PEM/NET to DER and attempt the import again. The OpenSSL command to do so is:

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -in <cert_file> -out <cert_out_file>`

Comment: This answer led me to what appears to be the fix. In my case, the cert turned out to be DER format already. I tried running `openssl x509 -in MYCERT.cer -text` but it gave an error, so I tried `openssl x509 -in MYCERT.cer -inform der -text` and it worked, telling me the cert is already in DER format. I changed the name of the cert from `*.cer` to `*.der`, and then dragged it on, and it worked. The intermediate cert will appear in Settings>General>Device Management on the simulator. The Dev Mgt section won't exist until the cert is on there.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work by simply renaming the file from `.cer` to `.der`.

First, export from Keychain Access (this makes the certificate in DER format).

Still, iOS Simulator seems to be very picky about what certificates can be installed via drag and drop.

- Root certificates: `.cer`
- Intermediate certificates: `.der`

Both files are in the DER format, but apparently the file extension is what Simulator uses.

After adding intermediate certificates, go to Settings > General > Device Management and install the profile (thanks to @James in comment on other answer).